# Macrobenchmark throws INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, macrobenchmark

We want to measure our (multi module) app performance. I setup macro benchmark but it's not start. When i try to start benckmark, it's throws this message:

```
Failed to install APK(s): /*****.apk
INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.*** signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!
com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.*** signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!
```

Benchmark module build gradle:

```
   buildTypes {
    // This benchmark buildType is used for benchmarking, and should function like your
    // release build (for example, with minification on). It"s signed with a debug key
    // for easy local/CI testing.
    create("benchmark") {
        isDebuggable = false
        signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("debug")
        matchingFallbacks += listOf("debug")
    }
   }

...

   dependencies {
       implementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
       implementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
       implementation("androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.2.0")
       implementation("androidx.benchmark:benchmark-macro-junit4:1.2.0-alpha09")
   }
```

Benchmark variant on app module's gradle:

```
   create("benchmark") {
        val releaseForInitWith = getByName("debug") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            isShrinkResources = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }

        initWith(releaseForInitWith)

        signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("debug")
        matchingFallbacks += listOf("debug")
        isDebuggable = false
   }
```

Could you help, how can i fix this?

Comment: try this command `./gradlew cleanManagedDevice` and rerun the task

Answer (score 0):

> INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.*** signatures do not match previously installed version; ignoring!

This occurs when the device has a version of the app installed which was signed with a different certificate. That could have been a version installed from the Play Store or a version not signed with the `signingConfig` used for your `benchmark` build. In this case, `signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("debug")`.

The easiest way to resolve this is by executing `adb uninstall $appPackage` and then running the benchmark again.